# How to get parameter from url action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-action

i have this medthod:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string Id) {

        return PartialView("Edit",Id);
    }
```

and myView:

```
<a class="openEditdialog" onclick="javascript:OpenWindow('@Url.Action("Edit", "RegisterBrand", new { Id = @item.Id})')" ></a>
```

but, i don't know why Id variable in Edit() is null????

Comment: Shouldn't `new { Id = @item.Id})` be `new { Id = @Model})`?

Comment: what URL does your @Url.Action actually render?

Comment: @Chandu item is instance of Model.

Comment: @David i don't know why parameter item.Id is null also when i try <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "RegisterBrand", new { Id = @item.Id})"> every thing is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try This one i hope this will be helpful..

**In view**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { Id = @item.ID})">TestLink</a>
```

In your Home controller

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When returning a partial view and specifying the model i.e.

```
return PartialView("Edit",Id);
```

and `Id` is a string, then the reference to `Model` in your partial view *will be a string*, where your code suggests there is some magical object with an `.Id` property on it. Your view would use `@Model` to get the string. e.g.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "RegisterBrand", new { Id = @Model })">link text</a>
```